# What is this print called and how to create it?

Tags: artwork, creative-process

I was in a store and saw this artwork for sale:

[image: example]

I want to make a print in the same style from one of my photographs.

If I had to guess, this looks like a chroma key or someone spent a lot of time cropping.

It looks to be 3/8" glass or acrylic substrate.

What do you call this type of print/process?

What type of camera resolution would one need to accomplish this?

EDIT1:
Style:  I meant I want to create a poster size glass image using one of my photos with the background removed.

Type: I meant to ask for the minimum resolution needed to create a poster size glass image, as pictured.

Comment: Hi Marinaio, can you describe in words what the style and type is what you're referring to? It will make your question more clear and easier findable for future people with the same question. Thanks!

Comment: @Saaru Lindestøkke  Will do

Comment: Regarding the minimum resolution there's this existing question: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/456/is-there-a-general-formula-for-image-size-vs-print-size

Comment: Regarding the black background there are several questions: 
https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7762/what-do-i-need-to-get-photos-with-a-unifom-black-background-not-with-post

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/98904/how-to-create-a-gray-black-color-background-in-a-photograph

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39456/black-background-post-processing-tips

Sorry, I edited your question before seeing that there was an answer already addressing it.

Answer (score 4):

That are actually 3 questions:

```
How to create a black background?
```

[What do I need to get photos with a unifom black background (not with post)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7762/what-do-i-need-to-get-photos-with-a-unifom-black-background-not-with-post)

[What is the easiest way to take a shot to remove the background?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65020/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-take-a-shot-to-remove-the-background)

```
How is that acrylic print called?
```

You just said it. While it has no special name, most call it just that: Acrylic Photo Print. It is a print that is then laminated to the back of a sheet of acrylic glass. Or in other cases printed to the back of the sheet and then sealed with either white paint or a sheet of thin white plastic.

Example https://www.whitewall.com/us/acrylic-prints

```
How many megapixels do I need for a big sized print?
```

[At how many megapixels should I render my image for a quality A1 print?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23595/at-how-many-megapixels-should-i-render-my-image-for-a-quality-a1-print/23609#23609)

```
And the meta question: How do I create such a picture?
```

Go out and shoot. ;o) Review, learn what has gone wrong, improve, repeat.

Comment: Acrylics are sometimes printed directly to the reverse of the sheet, then over-sprayed with solid white. I have a few here I had made that way. Similar end-result, visually, but it's not a laminate & the reverse can get scratched if you're not careful.

Comment: I will add that to the answer.

Comment: @Kai Mattern  Thanks for the info and the acrylic printing site.  1st take-away is that this is a very expensive process.  So I'll start small.  Appreciate the other links.

Comment: Shoot, with how expensive they are to make, I think step 1 is find a buyer ;-)